# Serverless AWS Lambda Edge: MalformedHandlerName

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, handler, serverless-framework

I'm following the below example to setup a Lambda Edge function:
https://www.serverless.com/blog/lambda-at-edge-support-added

**The code**: ./handler.js

```
// SAME CODE STRUCTURE AS ORIGINAL, JUST ADDING A HEADER TO TEST
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {    
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const headers = response.headers;
    headers['test-lambda-edge'] = [{ key: 'test-lambda-edge', value: 'working' }]
    callback(null, response);
};
```

**The Config**: ./serverless.yml

```
# SAME CONFIG AS ORIGINAL, JUST CHANGING eventType and origin
service: mylambda
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
functions:
  cfLambda:
    handler: functions/handler.cloudfront
    events:
      - cloudFront:
          eventType: origin-response
          origin: https://example.org
```

**The function deploys properly:**

```
$ sls deploy
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading mylambda.zip file to S3 (554 B)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
................
Serverless: Stack update finished...
Service Information
service: mylambda
stage: dev
region: us-east-1
stack: mylambda-dev
resources: 8
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  CloudFront - ---------------.cloudfront.net
functions:
  cfLambda: mylambda-dev-cfLambda
layers:
  None
```

I am using the **Amazon CloudFront Modify Response Headers** test template for testing.

**Attempt 1) with the same handlers naming as article**
I get the below error, which I can understand as the article seems wrong, the cloudfront function isn't defined:

> "errorMessage": "functions/handler.cloudfront is undefined or not
> exported"

**Attempt 2) Trying to fix serverless.yml**
I replaced `handler: functions/handler.cloudfront` with `handler: functions/handler` to match the code and I get the below error:

> {"errorType":"Runtime.MalformedHandlerName","errorMessage":"Bad
> handler","stack":["Runtime.MalformedHandlerName: Bad handler","    at
> _splitHandlerString

If I look at the official doc, the handler naming is the same (ie `exports.handler =` ):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-how-it-works-tutorial.html

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
```

**Q: How should I name my handler in the code/config?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the catalog structure that you're using looks like this:

```
├── handler.js
└── serverless.yml
```

and the name of the exported handler is `handler` and lives in `handler.js` file then the correct config will look like this:

```
service: mylambda
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
functions:
  cfLambda:
    handler: handler.handler
    events:
      - cloudFront:
          eventType: origin-response
          origin: https://example.org
```

First part is the path to the module and after `.` you reference specific function exported in that module. For `handler: functions/handler.cloudfront` to work, you'd have to export `cloudfront` function in `./functions/handler.js` file.